# Opencv: Selecting pixel with mouse

Tags: opencv

I'm using the [cv2.setMouseCallback](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=mouse#cv.SetMouseCallback) function to select a pixel of an image shown in a window.
The callback function returns an x and y integers that represent the position of the pixel in the image, but paying attention to it's behaviour it seems to me that doesn't return the pixel you are over but the rounded value of a point in an imaginary axis.

[image]

If you look at the two first images, in both the mouse is over the pixel 0,0 but the result is diferent if you move closer to other pixels.

Ok. I know in a real image the error is insignificant, but is this a bug?

```
   cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) # Can be resized
   cv2.resizeWindow('image', self.w, self.h) #Reasonable size window
   cv2.setMouseCallback('image',self.mouse_callback) #Mouse callback
   while(not self.finished):
      cv2.imshow('image',self.img)
      k = cv2.waitKey(4) & 0xFF
      if k == 27:
         breakim
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()


   # mouse callback function
   def mouse_callback(self,event,x,y,flags,param):
      if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
         print x, y
```

Comment: Did you resize the original 20x20 image to something like 500x500 (zoomed in)?

Comment: Yes. Do you think that introduced some malfunction?

Comment: of course.. those big squares arent just one pixel, they contain (500/25)x(500/25) = 625 pixels if you resize the image as such. Decrease your screen resolution to the lowest possible, if you want to see the pixels from closer and check the behaviour.

Comment: mmm I understand obviously each one of this squares is really a lot of pictures, but anyway it's not showing the real pixel number that would be a much bigger number. I just wanted to point out that at least when zooming the image it doesn't work strictly correctly.

Comment: Actually, the best way to check the behaviour without resizing is going until the left or bottom image border. For example in the very last left pixel of a 1000px width image x should be 999. Instead it's saying 1000, so it's actually a bug...

Comment: Maybe, or maybe not. You should check source code of those events and flags (related to mouse_callback) from python interface of opencv.

Comment: well, nevermind, i see its fixed right now. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug should be fixed in future releases.

http://code.opencv.org/issues/3409 if interested.